# Best easy way to partition a room

Tags: garage, partition

I'm looking for a simple way to partition an area in my garage to be a TV/Game room for the kids.
I don't want to build a "real" permanent room. But I would like it to have, as much as possible, a nice cozy feel to it.
The first level I was looking at was just getting some partitions like this the picture below. Any idea for something more appropriate would be welcomed.
[image]

Comment: Is the garage still going to be used for parking cars or any other machine that carries gasoline or an internal combustion engine?  If so, we have a whole different conversation about safety and codes to consider.

Comment: No. There won't be any car or such in the garage. It is otherwise used for storage and the washer/dryer

Comment: How about curtains?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want a bit more permanence, take a look at this site. It's an [Ikea hack on a PAX to divide a room with sliding "doors"](http://www.ikeahackers.net/search/label/hack%20of%20the%20year). I like the site anyway, it's useful and between it and this there isn't anything you can't build.

Essentially, this guy used huge sliding doors to section off parts of his studio apartment, and the huge benefit was that he could close some parts off and open others to rearrange the room, like closing off the bed room when he had company.

Comment: I think you can purchase the doors from the PAX unit separately too.